# I wrote the code to scrap data from a website and store in a csv, but I can only use request and lxml module. I can use xpath not beautifulSoup

Tags: python, request, lxml

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import os
import csv
s = requests.session()
headers_dict = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"}
#s.headers = headers_dict
r = s.get("https://www.scrapethissite.com/pages/simple/", headers = headers_dict)
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
rows = tree.xpath('//*[@id="countries"]/div')
print(rows[0].text_content())
# Create a CSV file to store the data
csv_file = open('CountryInfo.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['Country', 'Capital', 'Population', 'Area'])
for row in rows:
    country_name = (row.xpath('//*[@id="countries"]/div/div[4]/div[1]/h3'))[0]
    #print(country_name.text_content())
    country_capital = (row.xpath('//*[@id="countries"]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/span[1]'))[0]
    population = (row.xpath('//*[@id="countries"]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/span[2]'))[0]
    area = (row.xpath('//*[@id="countries"]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/span[3]'))[0]
    csv_writer.writerow([country_name.text_content(), country_capital.text_content(), population.text_content(), area.text_content()])
print("Program Executed")
```

but it only the writes the first country name, capital etc. and I understand why its happening but I want to scrape all the details how can I perform the operation.

I tried using the for loop but not getting the desired output that is: to have a csv that contains all the countries with their details.

The website url is: https://www.scrapethissite.com/pages/simple/

Answer (score 1):

In terms of XPath and Python, if you select `rows = tree.xpath('//*[@id="countries"]/div')` and then use `for row in rows:`, I would all XPath selections on `row` to be relative e.g. `country_name = row.xpath('div[4]/div[1]/h3')[0]` instead of `country_name = (row.xpath('//*[@id="countries"]/div/div[4]/div[1]/h3'))[0]`.

The same for the other data.